# How to restructure json object django rest framework?

Tags: json, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

This is my `json` response from `Django`

```
{
    id:"123"
    latitude: "37.5111",
    longitude: "126.9743"
}
```

Want **output** like this:

```
"123": {
     latitude: "37.5111",
     longitude: "126.9743"
}
```

**serializers.py**

```
class SearchSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = IpGeo
        fields = [
            # 'id',
            # 'metadata',
            'latitude',
            'longitude'
        ]
```

**views.py**

```
class Search(ListAPIView):

    queryset = IpGeo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SearchSerializer
```

Answer (score 1):

serializers.py

from rest_framework import serializers

```
class SearchSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    custom_field = serializers.SerializerMethodField()


    class Meta:
        model = IpGeo
        fields = [
         'custom,'

        ]
   def get_custom_field(self):
      d = {}
      d[str(self.id)] = dict(latitude=self.latitude,longitude=self.longitude)
      return d
```